# How to shuffle an array except for fixed positions

Tags: javascript

There is a playlist that consists of tracks and jingles:

```
var arr = [         
    {'title': 'jingle fixed'},
    {'title': track 0},
    {'title': track 1},
    {'title': 'jingle fixed'},
    {'title': track 2},
    {'title': 'jingle fixed'},
    {'title': track 3},
    {'title': track 4},
    {'title': track 5}
];

function shuffle(playList) {
    let currentIndex = playList.length, randomIndex;
    
    while (currentIndex != 0) { 
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex--;

        // How to except by playList.title?
        [playList[currentIndex], playList[randomIndex]] = [playList[randomIndex], playList[currentIndex]];
    }
  
    return playList;
}
```

I need to randomize (shuffle) only the tracks, and leave the jingles in their position.

What is expected:

```
[           
    {'title': 'jingle fixed'},
    {'title': track 4},
    {'title': track 1},
    {'title': 'jingle fixed'},
    {'title': track 5},
    {'title': 'jingle fixed'},
    {'title': track 3},
    {'title': track 0},
    {'title': track 1}
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues did you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest method: for each non-jingle, pick non-jingle tracks at random, removing each one from the non-jingle array so it can't be picked twice.

```js
let t = [ {'title': 'jingle fixed'}, {'title': 'track 0'}, {'title': 'track 1'}, {'title': 'jingle fixed'}, {'title': 'track 2'}, {'title': 'jingle fixed'}, {'title': 'track 3'}, {'title': 'track 4'}, {'title': 'track 5'}];
let m=i=>i.title!=='jingle fixed', f=t.filter(m);
t = t.map(i=>m(i)?f.splice(~~(Math.random()*f.length),1)[0]:i);
console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure someone could find a prettier solution as I think this has a quite high algorithm complexity (copy an array, filter it, sort it and recreate an array mapping the first one...), but it works.

```js
const tracks = [{
    title: 'jingle fixed'
  },
  {
    title: "track 4"
  },
  {
    title: "track 1"
  },
  {
    title: 'jingle fixed'
  },
  {
    title: "track 5"
  },
  {
    title: 'jingle fixed'
  },
  {
    title: " track 3"
  },
  {
    title: "track 0"
  },
  {
    title: "track 1"
  }
];

const shuff_tracks = tracks.filter(t => t.title !== "jingle fixed");
shuff_tracks.sort(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % 2 === 0 ? 1 : -1);

let tr_i = -1;

const out = tracks.map(t => {
  if (t.title === "jingle fixed") return t;
  return shuff_tracks[++tr_i];
});

console.log(out)
```